# The same radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to know why the following power series share the same radius of convergence.

(1) $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_k(z-z_0)^k}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_k(z-z_0)^k} -a_0$

(2) $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_{k+1}(z-z_0)^k}$ and $(z - z_0)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{a_{k+1}(z-z_0)^k}$

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Question (2) is a trick, designed to see if you are awake.  Question (1) is harder, and involves some understanding of radii of convergence.

Comment: @kimchilover I love kimchi too. I guess I could use the ratio formula for (2) but struggling to see why (1) is true.

Comment: The two series in (1) differ in that one of them is missing the $k=0$ term.  The radius of convergence depends on what happens as $k\to\infty$; changing finitely many terms will not affect that limiting behavior.

Comment: @kimchilover ah!! I got it, thanks a bunch